# Why does $aH = Ha \neq ah = ha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

For normal subgroups...How come $aH = Ha$ does not imply that $ah = ha$ for all $h \in H$?

I'm showing that every subgroup of a commutative group is normal and I thought I had it on that one but apparently not...?

Comment: Certainly you can say that _since_ $ah=ha$ for every $a, h\in G$ where $G$ is commutative, then $aH=Ha$ for every subgroup $H\subset G$ and so each subgroup of a commutative group is normal.  But the implication doesn't go the other way.

Comment: Isn't it not merely normal, but also quotient, as the left coset = right coset?

Comment: You've got it backwards, I think; $H$ is a _normal_ subgroup, while what's 'left over' - the different cosets of $H$ within $G$ - form the _quotient_ subgroup $G/H$.

Answer (score 4):

Saying that $aH=Ha$ is equivalent to saying that for each $h\in H$ there is $h'\in H$, possibly different from $h$, such that $ah=h'a$. Equivalently, $aHa^{-1}=H$, which says $aha^{-1}$ is in $H$ for every $a$, so $aha^{-1}=h'$ an element of $H$, but not necessarily $h$ itself.

Take for example $Q_8$ the quaternion group. Then every subgroup is normal, for example, $\langle i\rangle =\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ is, but $kik^{-1}=i^{-1}\neq i$.

Comment: Stop typing faster than me >:(

Comment: Ah I see...But for our case with commutative groups, then $ah$ certainly equals $ha$ so it is easy to see that $aH = Ha$, yes?

Comment: It is pretty much the definition of a quotient group, isn't it? $ah = ha$ for all $h \in H$ so the left and right coset is the same.

Is every commutative subgroup a quotient group?

Comment: @user3200098 Certainly, if $G$ is abelian, every subgroup is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively clean counterexample: let your base group $G$ be the group of *linear isometries* of $\mathbb{Z}$; this is the group of all maps $\{m(z):z\mapsto jz+a\}$, where $j\in\{\pm 1\}, a\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Let $H\subset G$ be the subgroup of translations by integers (i.e. those maps with $j=1$), and $a$ be reflection about the origin (i.e., multiplication by -1, the map with $j=-1, a=0$).  Then you can see that $aH=Ha$ — every translation-and-reflection is equivalent to some reflection-and-translation.  However, if $h\in H$ is translation by $+1$, then $ah\neq ha$; for instance, the former maps $x=1$ to $h(a(x)) = h(-1) = 0$, while the latter maps $x=1$ to $a(h(x)) = a(2) = -2$, so clearly they can't be the same isometry.  Instead, for this $a$ we have that $ah=h^{-1}a$ for every $h\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course if your group is commutative then $ah=ha$ for all $h,a$ in the group, not only in the subgroup. $aH = Ha$ does not imply that because an element of the first, say $ah$, is surely an element of the second, but in general for another element of $H$, say $h'$. Try with a non commutative group, like $S_3$ for instance.